# How to Stream Mp3 music from web using Python PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to stream mp3 file from web using python PyQt5.I have researched a lot and only found code for streaming wav file.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
import urllib.request
import threading
import time

class Streamer:
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.url = url
        self.fancy = urllib.request.URLopener()
        self.web = self.fancy.open(self.url)
        self.content_len = int(self.web.headers["Content-Length"])
        self.data = self.web.read(1024*1024)
        self.buffer = QBuffer()
        self.buffer.writeData(self.data[250:])
        self.buffer.open(QBuffer.ReadWrite)
        threading.Thread(target=self.stream).start()

        self.format = QAudioFormat() 
        self.format.setSampleRate(48000)
        self.format.setChannelCount(2)
        self.format.setSampleSize(16)
        self.format.setCodec("audio/pcm")
        self.format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
        self.format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.SignedInt)

        self.audio = QAudioOutput(self.format)
        self.audio.start(self.buffer)
    
    def stream(self):
        # while True:
        #     self.sound_data = self.web.read(1024*1024)
        #     if not self.sound_data:
        #         break
        #     self.buffer.buffer().append(self.sound_data)
        #     time.sleep(2)
        while len(self.data) < self.content_len:
            self.sound_data = self.web.read(1024*1024)
            self.buffer.buffer().append(self.sound_data)
            self.data+=self.sound_data
            time.sleep(2)
        self.buffer.buffer().clear()    
        del self.data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    streamer = Streamer("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PremKumarMishra/Stream-Songs/main/Audio.wav")
    app.exec_()
```

I checked but cant add MPEG-3(mp3 codec) codec in QAudioFormat.So this current code does not work for mp3.

Comment: If it's a simple multicast, try with [QMediaPlayer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html).

Comment: @musicamante i know but i want to stream from web and QMediaPlayer does not have any support for streaming from internet

Comment: Who told you that? It perfectly works with web urls, it only might have problems with HLS playlists, but that's another story. If it's simple mp3 files from an online streaming radio, it will work just fine.

Comment: which function streams from web ? @musicamante

Comment: The same function that is used to load any media: `mediaplayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl('https//some.url/file.mp3')))`.

Comment: @musicmante thanks but i would like to append buffers myself not by QUrl.i want to know what qurl does to stream music then i will make myself.

Comment: QUrl does nothing of that, it's just an object used to represent url addresses and provide functionalities to access them ([see the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html)). If you want custom buffering, you need to provide a file stream as second argument of [`setMedia()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#setMedia) and implement its access. Maybe you can use a QNetworkReply.

Comment: Thanks I Checked it out but it requires a c++ Abstract class to work

Comment: No, the QIODevice argument is the accepted base class, that means that the argument must be an instance of a class that inherits from QIODevice, including existing Qt classes like QFile or, as already said, a QNetworkReply (which is what a QNetworkAccessManager returns for a network request). Note that in most cases, the buffer management of QMediaPlayer is fine enough for basic streams, you just need to ensure that the buffer state has reached 100 before actually starting playing.

Comment: @musicamante thanks but if buffer state has to be reached 100 before playing then is it actually streamer? it simply means you read all data of music

Comment: No. The buffer is managed by the backend, 100 means that it has reached a reasonable size to allow playing, not that it has read/downloaded the whole file. You just need it to reach 100 and then you can call `mediaPlayer.play()`. I suggest you to try it.

Answer (score 0):

The basic behavior of QMediaPlayer should be enough to manage buffering of simple audio streams, as the backend will consider the 100% of buffer size as enough to guarantee playing.

In case you want more control over the buffer state, you need to implement a custom QIODevice subclass to act as a middle layer between QMediaPlayer and the download process.

In the following example I'm using QNetworkAccessManager to download the stream, the `readyRead` signal of the QNetworkReply is then connected to a function that reads the raw bytes, and emits a buffer status considering the current available read data and the minimum size set for the buffer.

The first time the received data has reached the minimum size, it begins to emit the `readyRead` signal, and if the player has not been started yet (no media set), it sets the media using the Buffer instance, and is then ready to play.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtNetwork, QtMultimedia

url = 'https://url.to/stream'

Errors = {}
for k, v in QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(v, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.Error):
        Errors[v] = k

class Buffer(QtCore.QIODevice):
    buffering = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object, object)
    fullBufferEmitted = False
    def __init__(self, reply, minBufferSize=250000):
        super().__init__()
        self.minBufferSize = max(200000, minBufferSize)
        self.reply = reply
        self.data = bytes()

        # the network reply is on another thread, use a mutex to ensure that
        # no simultaneous access is done in the meantime
        self.mutex = QtCore.QMutex()
        # this is important!
        self.setOpenMode(self.ReadOnly|self.Unbuffered)

        self.reply.readyRead.connect(self.dataReceived)

    def dataReceived(self):
        self.mutex.lock()
        self.data += self.reply.readAll().data()
        dataLen = len(self.data)
        self.mutex.unlock()
        self.buffering.emit(dataLen, self.minBufferSize)
        if not self.fullBufferEmitted:
            if dataLen < self.minBufferSize:
                return
            self.fullBufferEmitted = True
        self.readyRead.emit()

    def isSequential(self):
        return True

    def readData(self, size):
        self.mutex.lock()
        data = self.data[:size]
        self.data = self.data[size:]
        self.mutex.unlock()
        return data

    def bytesAvailable(self):
        return len(self.data) + super().bytesAvailable()


class Player(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.playButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', enabled=False)
        layout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        self.volumeSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        layout.addWidget(self.volumeSlider)
        self.statusLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Waiting')
        self.statusLabel.setFrameShape(
            self.statusLabel.StyledPanel|self.statusLabel.Sunken)
        layout.addWidget(self.statusLabel)

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(volume=16)
        self.volumeSlider.setValue(self.player.volume())

        self.networkManager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.url = QtCore.QUrl(url)
        self.media = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(self.url)
        reply = self.networkManager.get(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(self.url))
        self.buffer = Buffer(reply)

        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)
        self.volumeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setVolume)
        self.player.error.connect(self.error)
        self.buffer.buffering.connect(self.buffering)

    def error(self, error):
        errorStr = 'Error: {} ({})'.format(
            Errors.get(error, 'Unknown error'), int(error))
        self.statusLabel.setText(errorStr)
        print(errorStr)

    def buffering(self, loaded, minBufferSize):
        self.statusLabel.setText('Buffer: {}%'.format(int(loaded / minBufferSize * 100)))
        if self.player.media().isNull() and loaded >= minBufferSize:
            self.player.setMedia(self.media, self.buffer)
            self.playButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.playButton.setFocus()
            self.statusLabel.setText('Ready to play')

    def play(self):
        if self.player.state() == self.player.PlayingState:
            self.player.pause()
            self.playButton.setText('Play')
        else:
            self.player.play()
            self.playButton.setText('Pause')


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = Player()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Note that:

- as soon as QMediaPlayer begins to read the stream, the buffer length will obviously become smaller, as there's no way to know or control how the backend access the stream: when the player is reading (which doesn't mean it's playing), it will read the stream anyway;
- due to the reason above, the shown buffer size is only "guessed" as soon as the media is set, based on the data read and the data received from the network reply;
- you might want to control the media player status in case the buffer goes too low (but you *must* consider what explained above), and eventually pause it;

Comment: it does not work it gives me Error: ResourceError (1) when i click play after its ready to play

Comment: @DavidjohnGamer what url are you using?

Comment: https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3

Comment: Simple direct link of a mp3 file

Comment: @DavidjohnGamer Uhm, I can load that file, but I actually get some strange behavior when using sequential access. Let me do some further digging.

Comment: Sure Try finding .Thanks for your efforts